# Read in two similar files using AWK

Tags: bash, awk

Originally, I have only one file to read with some conditions. Here is the code...

```
awk -vid="$name" -F',' 'BEGIN{counter=0;}{if($15=="true"){counter++}}END{print id,counter}' file1
```

This code worked properly.

But now, I have to read on 2 files. 
The only difference between the 2 files is that file2 has 1 extra column.
file1 has 16 columns and file2 have 17 columns. There will be an instance that a row in file1 will exist in file2(plus the extra column)

POSSIBLE cases:

1. a row in file1 will exist in file2(disregarding extra column)
2. a row in file1 is different to file2
3. a row in file1 and file2 is similar except for 15th column(*true or false* as seen in the condition in the code above).

Now, my problem is that if I add file2 to the code above, like this...

```
awk -vid="$name" -F',' 'BEGIN{counter=0;}{if($15=="true"){counter++}}END{print id,counter}' file1 file2
```

**awk** will count the same entry twice if that entry exists in both files.

Question:
Is there any way to check the duplication aside from merging file1 and file2?

Comment: Please post some samples from both files and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to say something like:

```
awk -vid="$name" -F',' 'BEGIN{counter=0;}{if($15=="true" && !done[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14]++){counter++}}END{print id,counter}' file1 file2
```

BTW the fragment "END{print name,counter}" in the original code shoud be a typo of "END{print id,counter}", isn't it?